# wireshark lua string:byte() error

Tags: lua, wireshark

I have a string problem when writing my lua dissector. My packet looks like:

```
0000   00 00 00 69 00 10 00 01 00 00 00 ed 00 00 00 0c
0010   bf a6 5f ...
```

When debugging, the tvb looks the same

[image]

The byte at offset **0x10** is **0xbf**, but in my dissector function I got different result, here' my code:

```
local str = buf(0x10):string()
local x = string.byte(str, 1)
```

the variable **x** should be **0xbf**, but it's **0xef**, and some other offset are also 0xef:

```
local str = buf(0x11):string()
local x = string.byte(str, 1) -- also get 0xef, should be 0xa6

local str = buf(11):string()
local x = string.byte(str, 1) -- also get 0xef, should be 0xed
```

Seems big values will always get 0xef as result, like 0xa6/0xbf/0xed...

And small values will be correct, like 0x69/0x5f/0x0c...

I'm using the latest wireshark 2.0, is this a bug?

Comment: What is `:string()`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain well, post updated. And :string() is wireshark built-in function which converts tvb to a string

Comment: Try checking the values: `buf(0x10), buf(0x10):string()` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know much about Wireshark in particular, but I have a pretty good idea what's going on.

You are using Wireshark's `tvbrange:string([encoding])` function. The documentation I have found on the Wireshark website says that the default encoding is `ENC_ASCII`. Bytes in the range of 0x80-0xFF (for which you have reported problems) are not valid ASCII.

What Wireshark is probably doing is converting these to U+FFFD, Unicode's "Replacement Character". This is a standard practice for representing an unknown character in a Unicode string.

Then, Wireshark is probably encoding this string as UTF-8 when returning to Lua. The first byte of U+FFFD's UTF-8 encoding is 0xEF, so that's what you see.

If you want to get the raw byte values from a TVB, maybe try the `tvbrange:bytes([encoding])` function to get the values. e.g.

```
local bytes = buf(0x10):bytes()
local x = bytes:get_index(0) -- maybe 1, I'm not sure if it would be 0 or 1 indexed
```

There also may be some encoding you can pass to `tvbrange:string` that would do what you want, but I couldn't find any good reference for this.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `buf` refers to the parameter passed to your dissection routine, it is of type [`Tvb`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_Tvb). When you call it (as in, `buf(0x10)`), you create a [`TvbRange`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_TvbRange) instance. Both of them are documented here:
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html

tehtmi is spot on about the reason why you obtain the wrong results, `tvbrange:string()` returns a string using the ASCII encoding (since the encoding parameter was omitted).

A way to obtain the raw bytes buffer (rather than converting it to a ASCII or UTF-8 string) is:

```
local x = buf:raw(0x10, 1)
```

(Using offset 16 and length 1.)

If you ever think about using `buf(0x10):raw()` directly, note that for some reason this would return the full data source that is backing this Tvb. Maybe a bug or feature... Workaround:

```
local bytes = buf(0x10)
local x = bytes:raw(bytes:offset(), bytes:len())
```

Comment: Thanks, the `raw` function should make things a lot easier! I was looking at the documentation on the wiki, https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI/Tvb, which doesn't seem to mention `raw`.

Comment: @legoscia The Wireshark's Lua API Reference Manual will always be more accurate than the wiki because it is directly generated from the documentation in the Wireshark C code. See also the note on top of https://wiki.wireshark.org/LuaAPI