# How to display UTF-8 data in Lua script for wireshark

Tags: utf-8, lua, base64, encode, wireshark

I've been trying to represent binary in Japanese decoding by UTF-8, but still haven't figured out how to do it properly. Here is the codes.

```
vps_proto = Proto("vps", "VPS Packet")
Name_F = ProtoField.string("Name", "Name")
vps_proto.fields = {Name_F}

function RequestAccountPayloadParse(decoded_buf, pinfo, subtree)
    local PayloadNameRange = decoded_buf(0, 20)
    local PayloadName = PayloadNameRange:string(ENC_UTF_8)

    local payloadPacTree = subtree:add(decoded_buf(), pinfo, subtree)
    payloadPacTree:set_text("Payload")

    payloadPacTree:set_text:add(Name_F, PayloadNameRange, PayloadName)
end
```

The results showed in wireshark don't contain proper Japanese characters as seen below,

```
Payload
    Name: \350\213\227\...
```

which is supposed to be like

```
Payload
    Name: 山田太郎...
```

Could you find out the problems for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing these lines:

```
Name_F = ProtoField.string("Name", "Name")

local PayloadName = PayloadNameRange:string(ENC_UTF_8)
```

With these:

```
Name_F = ProtoField.string("vps.Name", "Name", base.UNICODE)

local PayloadName = PayloadNameRange:raw()
```

See also: [wireshark lua string:byte() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221316/wireshark-lua-stringbyte-error/35249289)

Comment: It worked out with these lines. Thank you very much.